# onclick redirect to url stored in php variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, redirect

I have the following table:

```
foreach ($forwards as $data):
    ?>

    <tr style="cursor: pointer" class="main_row">

        <td><?php echo $data['Offer']['id']; ?> </td>
        <td><?php echo $data['Offer']['name'];?> </td>
        <td><?php echo round($data['Stat']['ltr'],2)."%"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo round($data['Stat']['cpc'],2)."%"; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['Category']['name']?></td>
        <td><?php echo $data['Country']['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
     endforeach; ?>
```

now the idea is that when ever you click one of the `main_row` it should redirect to a new url. the problem is that the url contains an id for instance the url could look like `www.example.com/details/2` where 2 is the id.

This id is like all of the other data stored in a php variable: `$data['Offer']['id'];`

Now my question how can i redirect using both php and javascript? is there a work around? .

Please do note that i am fully aware that php i server side and javascript is not. it is because of this i am asking this question.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how the Javascript can get the ID from PHP? It can get it from the first `<td>` element in the `<tr>` that you clicked on.

Comment: the question is that i clearly have to redirect using javascript but the id (which is a part of the url) is stored in php

Comment: But PHP put it into the HTML, where Javascript can read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the ID from the first column in the row:

```
$(".main_row").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).find("td:first-child").text();
    window.location.href = 'www.example.com/details/' + id;
});
```

Comment: This was actually just what i needed however the other answers are perfect aswell!

Answer (score 2):

```
    <table>     
       <?php  foreach ($forwards as $data): ?>                        
                <tr data-link="http://www.example.com/details/<?php echo $data['Offer']['id']; ?>">    
                    <td><?php echo $data['Offer']['id']; ?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['Offer']['name'];?> </td>
                    <td><?php echo round($data['Stat']['ltr'],2)."%"; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo round($data['Stat']['cpc'],2)."%"; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['Category']['name']?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['Country']['name'] ?></td>
                </tr>
         <?php  endforeach; ?>
    </table>

   <script>
    $('table tr').click(function(){
         document.location.href = $(this).data('link');
    });
   </script>
```

if you use jQuery though.

Answer (score 1):

If you use jQuery do this:

```
$('.main_row').click(function(){
   window.location.href = "YOUR_URL"+$(this).attr('id');
});
```

And modify the html for the row to look like:

```
<tr style="cursor: pointer" class="main_row" id="<?php echo $id ?>">
```

This way - any time you click on the row it appends the row ID to the url and redirect you there.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you question correctly, your not looking for a redirect. To redirect in php, it must be done before you echo anything to the browser.

Because you want to "redirect" after your display is rendered, you should be using anchors.

```
<td><a href="www.example.com/details/<?php echo $data['Offer']['id']; ?>">
    <?php echo $data['Offer']['id']; ?> 
</a></td>
```

The anchor will direct the browser to the href url.